# subtração de duas propriedades double[]

Tags: c#, classes, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma classe chamada funcoes.cs

Preciso criar uma propriedade que armazene os valores X,Y iniciais e X,Y finais, pensei em:

```
    public  double[] PosicaoInicialXY { get; set; }
    public  double[] PosicaoFinallXY { get; set; }
```

então enviaria os parametros assim:

```
double[] valoresFinalXY = new double[2];
            valoresFinalXY[0] = 40;
            valoresFinalXY[1] = 5;
            funcoes.PosicaoFinallXY = valoresFinalXY;
```

e também para a posição incial

**Dúvida:**
Como poderia criar uma nova propriedade que fizesse a subtração de X,Y inicial - X,Y final ?

```
 double[] resultado = this.PosicaoInicialXY - this.PosicaoFinallXY; //??? não deu certo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma propriedade com um getter para fazer isso não resolve?

```
public double[] DifXY
{
    get 
    {
        return new[] {
            this.PosicaoInicialXY[0] - this.PosicaoFinallXY[0],
            this.PosicaoInicialXY[1] - this.PosicaoFinallXY[1],
            };
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** explicação do que está sendo feito:

O getter acima, retorna um novo array, com dois elementos, sendo que o primeiro calcula os valores respectivos de índice 0, e o segundo calcula os valores respectivos de índices 1.

Quando se usa `new[] { a, b, c, ... }`, na verdade se está criando um array, que é do mesmo tipo dos elementos a, b, c e assim por diante. Portando se ambos forem `double`, será criado um array do tipo `double[]`.

Exemplo:

```
double[] array = new [] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }; // criando array com os valores
```

Comment: Perfeito, só mais uma pergunta, porque o return new[] ?

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução alternativa, seria criar um tipo especializado em armazenar posições:

```
public struct Point
{
    private double x, y;

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double X { get { return x; } }
    public double Y { get { return y; } }

    public static Point operator -(Point a, Point b)
    {
        return new Point(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
    }
}
```

Veja que estou usando sobrecarga de operadores, para definir o que o sinal de subtração faz.

Assim, na sua classe, ao invés de trabalhar com arrays, você poderia usar o tipo especializado para fazer o que você quiser.

```
public class MinhaClasse
{
    public Point PosicaoInicial { get; set; }
    public Point PosicaoFinal { get; set; }

    public Point Diferenca
    {
        get { return this.PosicaoInicial - this.PosicaoFinal; }
    }
}
```

A vantagem deste método é que para que lê fica mais fácil de entender, além de você estar criando um tipo que encapsula as funcionalidades necessárias para manipulação de posições.

A desvantagem, é que vai ser mais um tipo em sua base de código.